# button color not changing android studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I’m unable to change the color of button in android studio.  When I edit the .xml file, then in preview it looks exactly like what I want.
But when I build the code and run it in my phone, then it has no effect.
Also button color is different than usual in mobile

Comment: Specify device version, & put the layout code also to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have not more xml files of same name or you may be doing changes in landscape xml file

Answer (score 1):

The emulator can be very finnicky depending on what version and device and hardware you have. Make sure that the theme you are using in the preview window in android studio is also set as the theme in the androidmanifest.xml file. If you want to know for sure what your app will look like, build the apk and put it on your phone.

I hope some of this info helps
Happy coding!